# How to change button states in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I've a series of buttons.

Each button has 2 different states: First State, Second State. The buttons changes into alternating states with each click.

In a scenario, if I click on Button1, it'll be in Second state. Then I click on Button2, Button2 will turn into Second State while Button1 (or any other buttons which is in the Second state) returns to the First State.

How do I do this in Appcelerator Titanium?

I've created the buttons like this

```
function createButtons(data){

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        //Creating each button
        var button  = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
            image:  data[i].path,
            value: 1
        });

        //Adding the buttons to the center view
        centerButtons.add(button);
    }
}
```

With each click, I'm changing the `value` of the button to either 1 or 2 to identify which state the button is in. 
The problem is, say when I click on Button1, I can change it's value but I don't know how to detect which **other** button(s) is/are already in the second state so that I can reset it to it's first state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following sample code will simply do your job. Here I have used buttons instead of imageView. You can change your code using it.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'white'
});
var currentView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : '#EFEFEF'
});
var button = [],top = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    top += 80;
    //Creating each button
    button[i]  = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        color : 'red',
        top   : top,
        width : '80%',
        value : 1
    });
    button[i].title  = 'State ' + button[i].value;
    button[i].addEventListener('click',changeState);
    //Adding the buttons to the center view
    currentView.add(button[i]);
}

var buttonState  = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    color  : 'red',
    top    : top + 80,
    title  : 'View button states',
    width : '80%',
});

var lblStates  = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    color  : 'red',
    layout: 'horizontal',
    top    : top + 160,
    text  : 'Click on show button to view the button states',
    width : '80%',
});

buttonState.addEventListener('click', showButtonStates);
currentView.add(lblStates);
currentView.add(buttonState);
win.add(currentView);
win.open();
//Changing the state of the clicked button
function changeState(e){
    e.source.value= 2;
    e.source.title  = 'State ' + e.source.value; 
    for(var i = 0;i<5;i++){
        if(e.source !== button[i]){
            button[i].value = 1;
            button[i].title  = 'State ' + button[i].value; 
        }
    }    
}
//To display the button state
function showButtonStates(){
    lblStates.text = "";
    for(var i =0;i<5;i++){
        lblStates.text = lblStates.text + '\nbutton' + (i+1) + ' ---> state: ' + button[i].value; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Either reset all of the buttons to be back in the original state whenever something gets clicked, then set the new state for the new button...
- ... or track the button (Variables?! What are those?) that was last changed, and revert it before setting the new state for the new button.